# Gradle dependency is not added when performing gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have added following cucumber dependency to gradle.

But when I do *gradlew project:build* it will not get added into the project,
What are the possible causes for this?

```
    dependencies {

   // Cucumber Test Dependencies   
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${apiDriver}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${testutilsSelenium}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${webDriverFactory}" 
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${cucumberJunit}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${cucumberJava}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${cucumberGuice}"    

   // Application Test Dependencies
   applicationEnvTestCompile configurations.compile
   applicationEnvTestCompile configurations.compileOnly
   applicationEnvTestCompile project(":application-test-environment")
   applicationEnvTestCompile files(weblogicJerseyClientJar)
   applicationEnvTestCompile files(weblogicJerseyCommonJar)
   applicationEnvTestCompile files(weblogicJerseyGuavaJar)
   applicationEnvTestCompile files(weblogicJerseyEntityFilteringJar)
   applicationEnvTestCompile files(wlfullclientJarPath);
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${unirestJava}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${amapispec}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${mxxml}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${junit}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${hamcrestLibrary}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${restAssured}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${restAssuredJson}"
   applicationEnvTestCompile "${amWebDriver}"
   applicationEnvTestRuntime "${slf4jApi}"

   applicationEnvTestRuntime "${javaxJmsApi}"
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJsonpJar)  
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyServerJar)  
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyJaxbJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyJsonJacksonJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyJsonProcessingJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyMoxyJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseyMultipartJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJerseySseJar)
   applicationEnvTestRuntime files(weblogicJsonpJaxrsJar) 

   // Database Environment Test Dependencies - Required for eclipse
   testCompile project(":database-test-environment")

   //Database Environment Test Dependencies
   databaseEnvTestCompile configurations.compile
   databaseEnvTestCompile configurations.compileOnly
   databaseEnvTestCompile project(":database-test-environment")

}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        plusConfigurations.add configurations.applicationEnvTestCompile
        plusConfigurations.add configurations.applicationEnvTestRuntime
    }
}
```

I have run the build as follows

gradlew mxapiext:mxapiext-web:build from the cmd

mxapiext:mxapiext-web is my project.and cucumber dependency will not added into my project

Comment: What do you mean it's not added to the build? test compile dependencies won't be included in a generated artifact.

Comment: I meant its not added as a reference library

Comment: Issue got solved , issues is with the soureSet which is not in my current working directory ,SourceSet has been assign as different project.